# Add entries on application.conf runtime. Is it possible?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I need to add some entries on application.conf on runtime. Is it possible? How?

I can not add those entries because i need to load them from database and i'll load it when application starts.

Thank in advance

Comment: How often do need to modify your application.conf ?

Comment: All the times that we have a new customer. Now we have near 2k customers and each customer has an own database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then why you do you put them in application.conf but not in a `object` or `trait`? Something like:

```
object ConfigFromDB {
    val config_val: Option[String] = loadfromdb()
    private def loadfromdb() = ...
}
```

or

```
trait ConfigFromDB {
    val config_val: Option[String] = loadfromdb()
    private def loadfromdb() = ...
}
```

Comment: because those entries are datasource connections and we are using anorm

Comment: but you can still do ur connection and get the `config_val` from the DB in `loadfromdb()`

Comment: but can i use a datasource? how can i use DB.withConnection("NAME") without application.conf?

Comment: add these line inside the trait /object
`val config = ConfigFactory.load`
`val db_name: String = config.getString("company.server.db_name")`

Comment: not work...DB.withConnection("DATASOURCENAME") must have "DATASOURCENAME" on application.conf and i would like to fill it dynamic

Comment: where you get the `DATASOURCENAME` from?

Comment: from Main Database.."Select Connection From Customers". I don't want to write it manually every time that we have a new customer, i want something dynamic.

Comment: How will you get data from a database without knowing the connection information?  Getting connection information from a database in order to connect to that database is a paradox.